# Adding an additional 2 drives to a Dell R230 2 drive system

Tags: dell-poweredge

I have a Dell R230 that was ordered as a 2 drive (sata) system. 
To add a 3rd and 4th drive I know I need a 4 drive cable and 2 more drive trays but I don't see any internal guides or mounting for the additional trays. I see a cover over the opening where drive 3 & 4 would go. Looking closer at the R230 case it appears that adding more drives may not be possible.

Comment: I believe the chassis comes with different options.  Some options are designed for two drives only. Short of replacing the chassis you may not be able to easily add additional drives.  You may need to pop the lid of the server and look inside to see if there is actually available drive bays.  A picture of the front, may be useful.  Or maybe plug the service tag into support.dell.com and get the 'System configuration' to see which options were purchased.

Comment: See https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/poweredge-r230_owners-manual_en-us.pdf page 55-57 for the 3 chassis options.